# After adding the ActionBarSherlock to my project my R.java file is gone

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I need to use an action bar in my app which is designed for API level 8. So I set about getting the ActionBarSherlock to go in my app.

I followed the instructions by making a new project for the action bar and then added it to my libraries in the Android tab of my project.

However I then lost my R.Java file and this bunch of errors pops up when I try and clean the project:

```
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:10: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:12: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:15: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:17: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView.Inverse'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar.Inverse'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:101: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAllCaps'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:55: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode.Inverse'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:328: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAllCaps'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:96: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:98: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:100: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:102: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:104: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:106: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title.Inverse'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:108: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:110: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:113: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:115: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:117: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:119: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:121: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2013-02-02 19:50:36 - FrenchVerbApp] C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0-0-g90939dc\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:14: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarWidgetTheme'.
```

What am I doing wrong here? My project's target API is level 13 and my minSdkVersion is 7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Part of the error references a folder called "values-v14". Since you are targeting api 13, you don't have those themes. Change you target api to 14 or higher and the errors should go away.

You normally set the target API to the latest API number available.

Comment: the target should always be the latest API version (lint mentions this, too).

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to set the Target API Level (of both the ActionBarSherlock project and yours) to same level (with ABS I always used a API level >=15).

You can do this using the Project Properties and clicking on the Android section.

Remember to do a Project Clean after changing the API Level.